# VBA - Wait for IE Element to load and copy to excel?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have a webpage like so (with a table):

```
Acount    Forecast     Date
A         A            01.12.2016
B         B            01.12.2016
C         C            01.12.2016
```

The webpage uses JAVA and my table element takes several seconds to load (even after IE has fully loaded or IE ready state is complete).

I want to copy the table data (by using my table element class name) into excel.
I have to factor in that even after my webpage has loaded, it will still take several seconds until my table has loaded and before VBA can reference the table element.

I am using the following code to try and do this, although i am getting this error:

> object doesn't support this property or method

on this line:

```
Set objCollection = html.getElementsByClassName("A22bb03b7e17940b4a081c992458916e4308")
```

Full code:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim ie      As InternetExplorer
Dim html    As IHTMLDocument
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://gbrlon02-sql-17/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fCutlass+Reports%2fManagement+Reporting%2fForwardOrdersSticksOnly+-+ForecastVariance+(Monthly+Report)"
While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
While ie.readyState < 4
    DoEvents
Wend
Set html = ie.document

Dim objCollection As Object
Dim objElement As Object


Set objCollection = html.getElementsByClassName("A22bb03b7e17940b4a081c992458916e4308")

Do
    i = 0
    While i < objCollection.Length
        If objCollection(i).className = "A22bb03b7e17940b4a081c992458916e4308" Then
            Set objElement = objCollection(i)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend

Loop Until Not objElement Is Nothing

If objElement.Length > 0 Then
    MsgBox objElement(0).innerText
End If
ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: @braX thanks, please see updated question

Comment: Try declaring the objCollection like: `set obCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("YOURCLASSNAME")`